# Reliability of Speed Boat Travel from Iquitos, Peru to Leticia, Colombia

Tags: tickets, ferries, peru, colombia, riverboats

This winter, my travel partner and I are embarking on an exciting journey to Peru. Part of our adventure includes traveling by speed boat from Iquitos, Peru to Leticia, Colombia.

We're currently considering two companies for this leg of our trip: Condor and Consorcio del Amazonas. However, we're a bit uncertain about their current operational status and reliability.

Current operation: Are Condor and Consorcio del Amazonas still actively operating this route?

Reliability: How reliable were these services in terms of safety, comfort, and adherence to schedules?

Comment: Hi Benjamin. Welcome. This site is very different from other sites on the internet. We are very focussed on factual questions and answers, not on personal experiences or anecdotes. Questions that ask for them are going to be closed. I've taken the liberty of editing your question to make it conform better to our site guidelines. Hopefully you will get some answers. Please have a look at [our help pages](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about how this site is different from others and how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance!